# is there any function to check values (only 0.25 steps) without declaring them?

Tags: php, jquery, regex, laravel-4

I am building a form and I want to check user inputs.
Allowed are only numbers from 0 to 30 with 2 decimals, but increase only in these steps 0.25 steps.
So for example this values are allowed: 0.25; 1.50; 3.75; ...
this values are not allowed 0.26; 1.53; ...
Can I check this without to declare all the allowed values?
I hope someone know what I mean and can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Would a regex be simpler to use? I added one in an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In jQuery you do this to check the value:

```
if ($("#num").val() % 0.25 == 0 && $("#num").val().length >= 0 
&& $("#num").val().length <= 30)) { 
 // Valid number
}
```

However, don't forget to controll the value server-side as well.

In PHP you can do this:

```
if (strlen($val) >= 0 && strlen($val) <= 30 && $val % 0.25 == 0) {

   // Valid number

}
```

Comment: Can u expand the function to check if the first char is a + or -? because some fields are allow the same values but only with + or -
E.g. -0.25; +3.5

Comment: Sure. Just use this code: `if ($("#num")val().charAt(0) == '-') { // a "-" }` . But to get it to work with the above function you have to change the valid values interval (change `$("#num").val().length >= 0` and `$("#num").val().length <= 30` to the values you want to be valid.

Comment: PHP will raise a warning on the modulo (division by zero). You should first multiply the value by 100 and do a modulo on 25 instead : ($val * 100) % 25

Answer (score 1):

The value should not leave a remainder when divided by 0.25

check `$value % 0.25 == 0`

And of course restrict it within your range

Comment: while this is fine for 0.25 (because it is a power-of-two), in general I would allow a tiny range to cater for floating-point precision. For example, if using a step of 0.1, check that for `$x = $value % 0.1`, `$x < 0.0001 && $x > -0.0001`. After validation passes, you can round the value to ensure it is a particular value.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple 'for'-loop:

```
var valid=false;
for(var i=0;i<30*4;i++){
   if(value==i*0.25)
   valid=true;
}
if(valid){
   // It's a valid input
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Edit: use modulo instead (see other posts), this can indeed be time consuming if you have a lot of code.

Comment: this is wasteful. See the other answers which use modulo.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value, cast it to Number (just to be sure), multiply it by 100 and check the rest of the division. In code:

```
var value = $('#yourFieldId').val();
// Cast it from String to Number
value = Number(value);

// now check that it is in the range
if( value < 30 && value > 0 ){

  if( (value * 100) % 25 === 0) ){
    return "It's valid"; //perhaps true?
  }

}
return 'not valid'; // perhaps you want to return false
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dc8Jw/)</kbd>

```
if (this.value % .25 === 0 && this.value <= 30 && this.value >= 0 && this.value.trim().length)
```

Comment: If you copy paste a negative number it says: valid. OP wanted only values 0 <= x <= 30 to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<?php

// $i = 3.25;
$dec = explode('.', $i);
$dec = end($dec);

if($dec % 25 == 0 || $dec == 5)
    echo 'Accept';
?>
```

Comment: It's unncessecary to break loose the decimals from the whole number. You could do the modulo operation right away and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you use regex, this is a solution (if not, no problem)

```
 #  ^[+-]?(?:[0-9]|[12][0-9]|30)\.(?:[27]5|[05]0)$

 ^
 [+-]?               # optional + or -
 (?:
      [0-9]          # 0 - 9
   |  [12] [0-9]     # 10 - 29
   |  30             # 30
 )
 \.                  # .
 (?:
      [27] 5       # 25 or 75
   |  [05] 0       # 00 or 50
 )
 $
```

Or, with optional decimal place and trailing zero on '00' and '50'

```
 ^ [+-]? 
 (?:
      [0-9] 
   |  [12] [0-9] 
   |  30 
 )
 (?:
      \.
      (?:
           [27] 5
        |  [05] 0? 
      )
 )?
 $
```